# Trying to dynamically assign SQL Server name and Database

Tags: vba, ms-access

Not sure what I am doing wrong. When it passes the server name along, it's passing along txtlink3 instead of the server name. See screen shots for more details

[Server Connection after running code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmZF1.jpg).

[Form where the server Name and database name come from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN8es.jpg)

I appreciate the assistance.

```
Private Sub cmdlink1_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_cmdlink1_Click
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

Dim strServer As String
Dim strDatabase As String

strServer = txtlink3   'This comes from a Field in the form
strDatabase = txtlink4 'This comes from a Field in the form 


DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "ODBC Database", "ODBC; Driver={SQL Server};Server=txtlink3;Database=txtlink4;Trusted_Connection=Yes", acTable, "dbo.address", "AddressMS" ' Use for test SQLdb on matts workstation

MsgBox "Done"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

Exit_cmdlink1_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_cmdlink1_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_cmdlink1_Click
```

I have done something similar for access and it works fine, See code below

```
Private Sub cmdlink2_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_cmdlink2_Click
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

If DLookup("[license #]", "Ticket") <> DLookup("strlicense", "tblsmsettings") Or IsNull(DLookup("strlicense", "tblsmsettings")) = True Then
MsgBox "You don't have a License to use this product. Please contact the software vendor", vbOKOnly
Exit Sub 'be sure that they have a license to use this app
End If

Dim strFile As String
strFile = txtlink2
If Dir(strFile) = "" Then ' see if the file exists before dropping
MsgBox "The database specified does not exist"
Else
DoCmd.SetWarnings False

DoCmd.RunSQL "drop Table [Journal Disbursements]"
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "Microsoft Access", txtlink2, acTable, "Journal Disbursements", "Journal Disbursements"

DoCmd.RunSQL "drop table [Journal Receipts]"
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "Microsoft Access", txtlink2, acTable, "Journal Receipts", "Journal Receipts"

DoCmd.RunSQL "drop table [Journal General]"
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "Microsoft Access", txtlink2, acTable, "Journal General", "Journal General"

DoCmd.RunSQL "drop table [Journal Purchases]"
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "Microsoft Access", txtlink2, acTable, "Journal Purchases", "Journal Purchases"

DoCmd.RunSQL "drop table [Journal Sales]"
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "Microsoft Access", txtlink2, acTable, "Journal Sales", "Journal Sales"

DoCmd.RunSQL "drop table [Ticket]"
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "Microsoft Access", txtlink2, acTable, "Ticket", "Ticket"

MsgBox "Done"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End If

Exit_cmdlink2_Click:
    Exit Sub

Err_cmdlink2_Click:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume Exit_cmdlink2_Click
    
End Sub
```

Comment: It's passing "txtlink3" because that is the value in the ODBC connection string. Not only are you not concatenating variables but you are not even using the declared variables. Even in your Access code, you declare strFile but then use txtlink2. These declared variables aren't really necessary. Just reference the form controls `Me.txtlink2`.

Comment: Using declared variables has advantage in case form control names are changed. So if you are going to declare variables then use them.

Comment: @June7 I have tried the me.txtlink3 and Forms![frmLinkSQL]![txtlink3]. Neither work. Its just odd to me that the MSAcecss code works but I cant do the same things when linking to SQL Database.

Comment: I tested your code with my db and the syntax works. Are you now concatenating the variables? Edit your question.

Comment: Access linking code works because not having to concatenate dynamic elements.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to build connection string with dynamic elements, then must concatenate variable inputs.

```
DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "ODBC Database", _
     "ODBC; Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & strServer & ";Database=" & strDatabase & ";Trusted_Connection=Yes", _
     acTable, "dbo.address", "AddressMS"
```